# Select random record from mnesia

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

I have an mnesia table `t` that contains records with a single field `x`. How can I select a random value `x` from `t`?

To avoid the entire of process of mathematical pedantry: I don't care about the details of the random number generation, I just want my result to generally not be the same every time.

Thanks,

-tjw

Comment: i wish you could tell us the nature of the primary keys in table t, also, the nature of the record.I think your question is how you select a random row from a mnesia table, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `mnesia:all_keys/1` (or dirty equivalent) function and the `random` module.

```
random_value(Table) ->
    Keys = mnesia:dirty_all_keys(Table),
    Key = lists:nth(random:uniform(length(Keys)), Keys),
    [#record{x = X}] = mnesia:dirty_read({Table, Key}),
    X.
```

Don't forget to initialize your seed using `random:seed/3`.

Comment: mnesia:all_keys/1 may be a very expensive operation, depending on the table size, as well as the nature of his application.As the table grows, the function above will most likely consume more memory.

Comment: True, however you have to have all keys to select one of them. You might be able to index the keys in a separate table (mnesia or ets) and have some algorithm select one without looping over them. Doing `mnesia:dirty_all_keys/1` with a table with 1 M elements takes 300 ms on my Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 5):

not really efficient but will work:

1. generate random integer X
2. get table size
3. get pointer using mnesia:first
4. iterate X times to random record
5. lookup record

more sophisticated:

1. create extra field containing integer
2. integer is incremented on ever set
3. create index over extra field
4. random number X
5. dirty read indexed row with X as a Key

one more:

1. use int as primary key
2. random int
3. retrieve the row

Each of those solution has important faults: concurrent write performance, read overhead etc.